# Получить список всех классов по конкретному namespace

Tags: php

Я нашел метод с помощью которого можно реализовать данную задачу:

```
$classes = get_declared_classes();
$implementsIModule = array();
foreach($classes as $klass) {
    $reflect = new ReflectionClass($klass);
    if($reflect->implementsInterface('Interface'))
        $implementsIModule[] = $klass;
}
```

Но вот незадача, моих классов нет в объявленных классах.
Как мне добавить все классы из папки в объявленные ?
Или быть может вы знаете другие методы вывода всех классов из папки.

Нашел еще один метод:

```
    $path = __DIR__;
$fqcns = array();

$allFiles = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path));
$phpFiles = new RegexIterator($allFiles, '/\.php$/');
foreach ($phpFiles as $phpFile) {
    $content = file_get_contents($phpFile->getRealPath());
    $tokens = token_get_all($content);
    $namespace = '';
    for ($index = 0; isset($tokens[$index]); $index++) {
        if (!isset($tokens[$index][0])) {
            continue;
        }
        if (T_NAMESPACE === $tokens[$index][0]) {
            $index += 2; // Skip namespace keyword and whitespace
            while (isset($tokens[$index]) && is_array($tokens[$index])) {
                $namespace .= $tokens[$index++][1];
            }
        }
        if (T_CLASS === $tokens[$index][0]) {
            $index += 2; // Skip class keyword and whitespace
            $fqcns[] = $namespace.'\\'.$tokens[$index][1];
        }
    }
}
```

Но и тут постигла меня неудача, мой фреймворк(laravel) видит в путях только папку storage, вообщем только генерированные итоговые страницы.
Напрямую прописать путь к нужной папке не получается.

Comment: Что значит "Напрямую прописать путь к нужной папке не получается."?

Comment: Например $path = '/var/www/html/mysite/App/Modules/Shelf/PartnersAPI';

Comment: И в чем проявляется это "не получается"? Ошибки какие?

Comment: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/var/www/html/mysite/App): failed to open dir: No such file or directory (View: /var/www/html/mysite/app/Modules/Shelf/Resources/Views/admin/partner-management/index.blade.php)

Comment: А этот путь ТОЧНО существует? Так то этот итератор никак на laravel не должен быть завязан.

Comment: Точно существует. У меня получилось запустить итератор только по пути где хранятся сгенерированные ларавелом страницы. 
/var/www/html/mycite/storage/framework/views

Comment: Если бы мне надо было искать классы в файле, то да.
Но мне нужно искать файлы в  конкретной папке.
Спасибо вам за попытки помочь.

Comment: Смотрите права на файлы и папки. Чудес не бывает. Либо с правами косяк, либо, таки, неправильно путь пишите.

Comment: Очень хотел бы я чтоб это была правда, но я поставил права 777 на все что есть на проекте и та же ошибка. 
А по поводу путей, так они скопированы из неймспейса класса который лежит в нужной мне папке.
Я много разных варианты пробовал путей - не получается. 
Оно вообще не хочет в целом по проекту искать. 
Пример:
"
"RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/App/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory "
Указываю $path = '/App';

Comment: В таких ситуациях нужно начинать проверять самые, как кажется, невероятные/детские ошибки. Поставьте перед созданием итератора `var_dump(is_dir($path)); var_dump(is_readable($path));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$check = "my\\name\\space\\";

function parseTokens(array $tokens) {
    $nsStart    = false;
    $classStart = false;
    $namespace  = '';
    foreach ($tokens as $token) {
        if ($token[0] === T_CLASS) {
            $classStart = true;
        }
        if ($classStart && $token[0] === T_STRING) {
            return [$namespace, $token[1]];
        }
        if ($token[0] === T_NAMESPACE) {
            $nsStart = true;
        }
        if ($nsStart && $token[0] === ';') {
            $nsStart = false;
        }
        if ($nsStart && $token[0] === T_STRING) {
            $namespace .= $token[1] . '\\';
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__ . '/class/'));
$regex    = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/^.+\.php$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
foreach ($regex as $file => $value) {
    $current = parseTokens(token_get_all(file_get_contents(str_replace('\\', '/', $file))));
    if ($current !== false) {
        list($namespace, $class) = $current;
        if($namespace === $check){
            echo $namespace.$class;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все оказалось как вы и говорили, проблема была в том что App писал с большой буквы...

Comment: И ваш код подошел лучше всех под данную задачу!
Благодарю за помощь и хорошего вам дня! ;)